# Why does Python Turtle need WIN.update() in #Game Loop?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I've written the following #Game Loop trying to teach my students a lesson. The turtle would not move or respond to any of the functions until I added the line WIN.update(). Why would that be necessary? Other turtle #Game Loops I've created have not needed it. When does it become a requirement to help the turtle respond to both key commands and user created functions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StDRx.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

In a turtle program, the `update()` is only *necessary* if you've previously done `tracer(0)`, and doesn't *directly* affect keyboard events.

However, your program isn't assembled properly as `while True:`, or equivalent, defeats an event-driven environment like turtle.  The addition of `update()` gave your program a chance to clear the event queue.  What we really should use is a timed event.  This is what I would have expected your program fragment to look like:

```
def game_loop():
    if RUNNING:
        Move()  # Move the Turtle

        Barriers()  # Barrier Check

        WIN.update()  # Only if Win.tracer(0) is in effect

        WIN.ontimer(game_loop, 100)  # Delay in milliseconds

WIN.onkey(Up, 'Up')
WIN.onky(Down, 'Down')
WIN.onkey(Left, 'Left')
WIN.onkey(Right, 'Right')
WIN.listen()

game_loop()

WIN.mainloop()
```

Note that `onkey()` and `listen()` do not belong in the game loop, they only need to be applied once.